# How to draw a colored square on event change using canvas

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas, html5-canvas

I want a blue square next to it to pop up. I want this to be a continuous process

let's take button clicks as the event which creates a new boxes (such as a red, blue and yellow button) where on click it spawns one, then another next to it and so on.

I have already attempted to do this utilizing both the DOM and CSS, but to no avail as my programming knowledge is not good. I have attempted to perhaps, append childs in the form of divs (I am not sure how that works).

I expect the output to be small differently colored squares which are pasted on the screen using canvas when it recognizes an event (such as a button click). This I will later attempt to adapt to the face recognition.

What must I do to achieve this result?

Theoretical results:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/auS7w.png

If possible, I would like it to loop from the start when it reaches the edge screen, so that it eventually fills the whole canvas. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a simple canvas in html so you can draw inside with javascript.

A good tutorial you can found here https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_intro.asp

```js
const lengthSquare = 50, marginSquare = 10, colors = ["red", "blue", ""];
var x = marginSquare, y = marginSquare;
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var width = canvas.width, height = canvas.height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var addSquare = function(color){
  if(y + lengthSquare > height){
   console.error("Too much squares");
    return;
  }
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.strokeRect(x,y,lengthSquare,lengthSquare);
  ctx.stroke();
  x += marginSquare + lengthSquare;
  if(x + lengthSquare > width){
   x = marginSquare;
    y += marginSquare + lengthSquare;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="addSquare('red')" value="AddSquare RED"/>
<input type="button" onclick="addSquare('yellow')" value="AddSquare YELLOW" />
<input type="button" onclick="addSquare('blue')" value="AddSquare BLUE" />
<br />
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="200" style="border:2px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```